# Convergent series with general term $a_nb_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following question.

> Suppose that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is a convergent series, with $a_n > 0$, and
>   suppose that $b_n > 0$ is a bounded sequence. Then show that the series
>   $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nb_n$ is convergent.

I would know how to do this if the sequence $(b_n)$ was monotonic, however cannot seem to work out how to do it when I am not given that information.
I was thinking that if the sequence bn converges to a limit it would also be possible, however am I correct in saying that just because a sequence is bounded does not mean it is convergent (I know the other way round is true).

Any tips or hinters would be helpful as I seem to have got myself in a pickle!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Since $(b_n)$ is bounded and $b_n>0$ there exists $B>0$ such that $b_n\le B, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Now, since $a_n>0$ it is

$$0\le \sum_{n=0}^Na_nb_n\le B\sum_{n=0}^N a_n,\forall N\in\mathbb{N}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $M \in \mathbb R$ with $|b_n| \le M$. Now you have $|a_n b_n| = a_n b_n \le M \cdot a_n$. Now you can apply the [direct comparision test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test)...

Answer (score 0):

You should larn a little LaTeX/mathjax so you could make our question more readable.

Hint: What does it mean that $b_n$ is bounded, could you use that to estimate 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nb_n
$$

Answer (score 0):

You know that a criterion of convergence is that
$$
\sup_p \sum_{i=n}^{n + p} a_ib_i \to_{n\infty} 0
$$

Here, you have
$$
\left|
\sum_{i=n}^{n + p} a_ib_i
\right|
= \sum_{i=n}^{n + p} a_ib_i \le \sup_{k} b_k  \sum_{i=n}^{n + p}a_i
\le \sup_{k} b_k\times   \sup_p \sum_{i=n}^{n + p}a_i
$$

and as $\sup_p \sum_{i=n}^{n + p}a_i \to_{n\infty} 0$ is independent of $p$, the series converges.